# Akka Stream Option output

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have created an Akka Stream which has a simple `Source`, `Flow` and `Sink`. With this I can easily send elements through it. Now I want to change this stream so that the `Flow` returns an `Option`. Depending on the result of the `Option` I want to change the output of the `Flow`.

[image]

Is it possible to create a construction like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the answers given at this time involve `Broadcast`. Please note that it might work in this specific example, but in more complex graphs `Broadcast` might not be a sensible choice.
The reason is that `Broadcast` always backpressures if at least one of the downstreams backpressures.
The best backpressure-aware solution is `Partition`, which is able to selectively propagate backpressure from the branch selected by the Partitioner function.

Example below (elaborating on one of the answer by T-Fowl)

```
  def splittingSink[T, M1, M2, Mat](f: T ⇒ Option[T], someSink: Sink[T, M1], noneSink: Sink[None.type, M2], combineMat: (M1, M2) ⇒ Mat): Sink[T, Mat] = {
    val graph = GraphDSL.create(someSink, noneSink)(combineMat) { implicit builder ⇒
      (sink1, sink2) ⇒ {
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        def partitioner(o: Option[T]) = o.map(_ => 0).getOrElse(1)
        val partition = builder.add(Partition[Option[T]](2, partitioner))
        partition.out(0) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case Some(t) ⇒ t } ~> sink1.in
        partition.out(1) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case None ⇒ None } ~> sink2.in

        val mapper = builder.add(Flow.fromFunction(f))
        mapper.out ~> partition.in

        SinkShape(mapper.in)
      }
    }
    Sink.fromGraph(graph)
  }
```

Comment: Agreed, `Partition` is a more appropriate shape to use.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have something like that

```
val source = Source(1 to 100)
val flow = Flow[Int].map {
  case x if x % 2 == 0 ⇒ Some(x.toString)
  case _ ⇒ None
}
val sink1 = Sink.foreach[String](println)
val sink2 = Sink.foreach[None.type](x ⇒ println("dropped element"))
```

You can make runnable graph with desired structure as following:

```
val runnable = source
  .via(flow)
  .alsoTo(Flow[Option[String]].collect { case None ⇒ None }.to(sink2))
  .to(Flow[Option[String]].collect { case Some(x) ⇒ x }.to(sink1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can view the flow with the 2 sinks as being a sink in itself. To construct more complicated Graph's we can use the functions provided in [GraphDSL](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphDSL$.html).

Consider, in a generic case

```
def splittingSink[T, M1, M2, Mat](f: T ⇒ Option[T], someSink: Sink[T, M1], noneSink: Sink[None.type, M2], combineMat: (M1, M2) ⇒ Mat): Sink[T, Mat] = {
    val graph = GraphDSL.create(someSink, noneSink)(combineMat) { implicit builder ⇒
        (sink1, sink2) ⇒ {
            import GraphDSL.Implicits._

            //Here we broadcast the Some[T] values to 2 flows,
            // each filtering to the correct type for each sink
            val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Option[T]](2))
            bcast.out(0) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case Some(t) ⇒ t } ~> sink1.in
            bcast.out(1) ~> Flow[Option[T]].collect { case None ⇒ None } ~> sink2.in

            //The flow that maps T => Some[T]
            val mapper = builder.add(Flow.fromFunction(f))
            mapper.out ~> bcast.in

            //The whole thing is a Sink[T]
            SinkShape(mapper.in)
        }
    }
    Sink.fromGraph(graph)
}
```

This returns a `Sink[T,Mat]` that, using the provided function, will map the incoming `T` elements into an `Option[T]`, which is then directed to one of the provided sinks.

An example of the usage:

```
val sink = splittingSink(
    (s: String) ⇒ if (s.length % 2 == 0) Some(s) else None,
    Sink.foreach[String](s),
    Sink.foreach[None.type](_ ⇒ println("None")),
    (f1: Future[_], f2: Future[_]) ⇒ Future.sequence(Seq(f1, f2)).map(_ ⇒ Done)
)

Source(List("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"))
        .runWith(sink)
        .onComplete(_ ⇒ println("----\nDone"))
```

Output:

```
None
None
None
Four
Five
None
----
Done
```

Usage of GraphDSL are discussed further in the documentation section about [Stream Graphs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html).

Comment: My own `Flow` is a bit more complex than the one I posted in my question. If I do this I end up with two `Broadcasts` which apparently doesn't work. Do you know how to get around that?

Comment: The problem with the diagram in your question is the 2 outputs from your `Flow`. A `Flow` is defined to have 1 input and 1 output. Looking at my example, the flow wrapping the provided function (`Flow[T,Option[T],_]`) could be replaced with whatever flow (of any complexity) you want.

Comment: You're answer works flawlessly. I guess there is a different problem which causes my Stream to crash. I'm using the same `Sink` at two points in my Stream. Do you know if that's a no go?

Comment: As far as I know, using the same `Sink` in multiple places shouldn't cause the graph to crash unless the `Sink` instance has some underlying resource (Consider a Sink that writes to a file and maintains the lock on that file). Glad that my solution works, I would recommend to take a look at the answer from svezfaz as they pointed out something which I neglected.

Comment: Thanks, will do! I also just realized my mistake was that I send two different `Flows` to my `Sink`. Obviously a `Sink` only has one input so I had to add a `Merge`\